# How to login with Google account in iOS device with Flutter, no Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I have successfully integrated Google login in android without Firebase. We are using MySQL. I have followed this YouTube [Flutter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5WgU6ERZzA&t=462s), but  I have no idea how to do it in iOS.

Please Flutter team, guide me through.